# Bash String Comparison with Spaces

Tags: bash

Alright all, I'm new to bash and having some issues comparing a string to another in a for loop.

```
   #loop through usb repo main folder to gather file names.  Then check in that folder to find out if 'repodata' exists.  If it does then do a createrepo -update if not then run a regular createrepo to make the file

RepoPath="/media/My Passport/RHEL_Repo/rhel-6-workstation-all"

for j in "$RepoPath"/*
  do
    if [[ "$j" != "$RepoPath/repodata" ]]
      then
        for repoDir in "$j"/*
          do

#I would like this to evaluate if the directory ends with a folder named "repodata"...it is currently incomplete
            if [[ -d "$repoDir"]] 
              then
                echo "$repoDir"
                echo folder exists
                #createrepo -v -update /media/My Passport/RHEL_Repo/rhel-6-workstation-all/$j
            else
                echo "$repoDir"
                echo does not exist
                #createrepo -v /media/My Passport/RHEL_Repo/rhel-6-workstation-all/$j
            fi
        done
    else
      echo Incorrect Eval
    fi
done
```

The issue is that the variable string "RepoPath" has a space in it.  This causes the loop to separate the first half into the first var and the second into another is evert path.  The inner nested "if" then evaluates to the "else" and prints each piece and echo "does not exist".

I'm stumped on this and was wondering if anyone could help me fix the issue which seems to be caused by the space in the path variable.  Thanks.

Comment: Quote it in the comparison the way you did in the initial loop. Quote `"$j"` too when you use it. Generally quote all variable expansions.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend for this kind of bug.

Comment: @Etan Reisner - thank you that got me closer to my goal.

Comment: @Charles Duffy - I didn't know that site existed.  It looks like it might be down right now, I'll check it out when it comes back.  Thank you.

Comment: @acslater1, it looks to be accessible to me, but if you're having trouble, it can also be downloaded and run locally; see https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck

Comment: This is a lot of work to trigger inclusion of the `--update` flag to `createrepo` since it doesn't hurt anything (that I'm aware of) to use it even when the repodata has not been created yet.

Comment: @Etan Reisner - you're right, part of this was to help me learn how to do it, but the --update flag does cut down a bit on time to create repo if I include the check for the need to update as well, which I have not included yet.  Well at least that was my understanding of it...

Comment: You missed my point. I wasn't suggesting that you ditch the `--update` flag. I was suggesting that you **always** use it. It doesn't hurt when no repodata exists yet.

Comment: Feel free to test it yourself (as you should) but I haven't seen it cause a problem (not that I use it much anymore) and the man page says "If metadata already exists" so it sounds like it should work that way. Oh, also, the flag is `--update` not `-update`.

Comment: You should have a space before the ]] in `if [[ -d "$repoDir"]] `.
(That would not fix your space-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some double quotes around your variable `$RepoPath`:

```
if [[ "$j" != "$RepoPath/repodata" ]]
```

You can wrap the whole string in the same quotes with no problem. *Actually, you don't need the quotes here because you're using bash's enhanced `[[` but it is still good practice*.

Also:

```
for repoDir in "$j"/*
```

Here, the `*` should remain unquoted so that it is expanded, rather than being interpreted literally. This one definitely needs to be quoted.

Comment: Thank you I see that now.  I made those adjustments and now the loop runs and echos out the correct paths of everything in the internal directories.  But everything evaluates to "Does not Exist".  I think because I made a mistake on the nested if "if [[ -d "$repoDir/repodata" ]'.  I need to check to see if the string ends in "repodata" and if so evaluate it to true.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean - perhaps you could edit your question to make it clearer?

Comment: @acslater1, do I understand that what you want is `[[ $repoDir = */repodata ]]`? Note that in that very specific case, you _don't_ want to quote the right-hand side (quoting the left-hand side wouldn't hurt anything)

Comment: Ok, I went ahead and updated the code.  I added the comment where it's not evaluating.  So every line in the output is saying "does not exist" even the directories that contain "repodata".  I know the "if" is incomplete now, I just don't know how to tell it to look to see if "repodata" exists in that path.

Comment: ...in the path, as in as part of the filename, or under the path, as in as a subdirectory?

Comment: @Charles Duffy - that was it.  Thank you VERY MUCH!

Comment: @ Tom Fenech, I just figured out what you were saying and yes you are correct.  I just realized that would duplicate the createrepo command on a single directory many times in some cases.  Thank you.